# Get text from HTML page with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I want to make an android app for getting stats. Lets say I want to get the kills and deaths from [www.oc.tc/MasterEjzz](http://oc.tc/MasterEjzz) and print them on the screen. I know that Jsoup is a good API to use, but I am unfamiliar with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sometimes when i parsed rss feed using jsoup, some websites rss used html in the description tag of rss feed.so i used the following: String description=android.text.Html.fromHtml(defaulttext).toString();
where defaulttext is the already parsed rss feed's description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Jsoup` introduction [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document),

To connect and download the document, you can use

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

Then to extract content from the `Document` ,

```
Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

For more information on `DOM Navigation` , [see](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

Comment: I understand that, but how do I parse it so I only get the text?

Comment: See the link for `DOM Navigation`, just get the `Element` using the `id` or `class` and use `text` to `attr` methods to get the information you need.

Comment: Ok, I wil try that and if I can get it to work, I will mark this post as solved. Thanks!